# Making state updates more readable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I'm practicing React by making a simple todo list with a task and a counter next to the task to indicate how many times I need to do it.

I would like to make the state update more readable by creating an object which contains the values that I want to update rather than just updating everything inline which can be kind of tricky to read, at least for me. However, it's not showing the item name or the counter isn't increasing on button click.

Here's the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-list-practice-5g45c?file=/src/index.js

```
Original approach:
   const duplicates = () => {
     if (!(input in items)) {
       setListItem({ ...items, [input]: 1 });
     } else {
       setListItem({ ...items, [input]: items[input] + 1 });
     }
   };

Refactored approach: 

  const checkDuplicate = () => {
    if (!(input in items)) {
      const newItem = {
        name: input,
        count: 1
      };
      setItems({ ...items, newItem });
    } else {
      setItems((items[input] += 1));
    }
  };

Button and ul

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          checkDuplicate();
        }}
      >
        add item
      </button>

      <ul>
        {Object.keys(items).map((el) => (
          <li>
            {el.name}: {items[el].count}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways to handle this, but this is one way that seems to work well for me:

[image: Edit kind-rain-hlzwq]

```js
function Todo() {
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState({});

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    const count = items[newItem] || 0;

    setItems({
      ...items,
      [newItem]: count + 1,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={(event) => {
          setNewItem(event.target.value);
        }}
        value={newItem}
      />
      <button onClick={handleAddItem}>Add Item</button>
      <ul>
        {Object.entries(items).map(([item, count]) => {
          return (
            <li key={item}>
              {item}: {count}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Most of the difference between my code and yours are irrelevant, just personal preferences. I do see a few issues in your `checkDuplicate` function, though:

```js
const checkDuplicate = () => {
  if (!(input in items)) {
    const newItem = {
      name: input,
      count: 1,
    };
    setItems({ ...items, newItem });
  } else {
    setItems((items[input] += 1));
  }
};
```

Here, you're using `setItems` to set it to an object that contains everything from the old object, but adding a new key/value pair. The key in your code is `newItem` and the value is `{ name: input, count: 1 }`.

I don't think you want the key to be `newItem`, I think you want it to be `input`, or something else at least.

Maybe this?

```js
setItems({ ...items, [input]: newItem });
```

And then in your `else` clause, you have:

```js
setItems((items[input] += 1));
```

This calls `setItems` with the return value of `(items[input] += 1)`, which is almost certainly not what you're going for. Instead, I think you want to do basically the same thing you're doing in your `if` clause, but instead just increment the count of the one that has the duplicate `key`.

Maybe this?

```js
setItems({
  ...items,
  [input]: {
    ...items[input],
    count: items[input].count + 1,
  },
});
```

There are other ways to do that sort of thing, but the important thing is to not mutate `items` when you increment `count`; you'll need to construct a whole new object that includes the incremented `count`.

Lastly, if you look at my code's `<li>`, you'll see I added a `key` prop to it. This is not your issue, but it's worth reading about and including in your code when you map over lists to generate JSX like you're doing. Read about [React Keys and Lists here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Definitely take my code with a grain of salt. I don't have access to all of your code, and so I put something together quickly to try to help unblock you. I left out some stuff that you had, like the `name` key in your items object.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting this together. 
I think I was really confusing myself in trying to shape the items state. I initially started with an array of objects but when adding the counter feature to the todo item I did not want to have to iterate through the item's array to find a matching todo item and increase its counter, rather my thought was to use an object so look up has constant time complexity.

Comment: I just saw your approach on the codesandbox. 
I was curious to know why we have to add brackets around the `[input]` key in setState and it can't just be `input` since it's just a string.

`
    setItems({
      ...items,
      [newItem]: count + 1
    });
`

Comment: @Verde92 The brackets make it a dynamic key, so that the key is equal to the value of variable, rather than the literal name "input" or "newKey" or whatever. I think that's what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";

// TODO: build a todo app which can:
//  1. add items to a list (render below input)
//  2. iterate a counter next to each item

// We should use arrays for this use case, there's no restriction of using plain object
const Todo = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const checkDuplicate = () => {
    const index = items.findIndex((item) => item.name === input);

    // if the item is already in array we get its index
    if (index !== -1) {
      const newArr = [...items];
      newArr[index].count += 1;
      return setItems(newArr);
    }

    // if the item is not in an array already we append it
    setItems([
      ...items,
      {
        name: input,
        count: 1
      }
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>TODO LIST</h1>
      <input value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          checkDuplicate();
        }}
      >
        add item
      </button>
      <ul>
        {items.map((el) => (
          <li>
            {el.name}: {el.count}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```